# Escaping in sprintf

Tags: c, printf

I want to read an escaped sequence from a file where it is stored verbatim.

At some point my call ends up in one of the ansi-c formatted functions

```
sprintf(target, format, ...);
```

my problem manifests without the args part - so don't worry about the details of that.

the format string is loaded from a file and stored in a buffer. 
`'\\' 'r' '\0'`  ( the file contains `'\\' 'r' '\0'` )

I want the target to store "`\r`", but my target always ends up like `'\\' 'r' '\0'`.

How can I solve this problem?

---

Edit:

To clear up my problem.

The textfile contains three characters - `'\\' 'r' '\0'`

Those three are read and need to be stored like the two characters `'\r' '\0'`

The user is free to change the file contents and i will have to find a way to interpret the line in the file like i wrote it before compile time in my editor.

Comment: the whole thing is embeded into a tested module and i need to keep the arguments. I need sprintf to recognize the escape.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear (although I appreciate this kind of thing is hard to describe!); does this text file contain three characters, or 13?

Comment: If you give a working example of what you're doing it'd help make this clearer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying!  I think I now understand your situation.

Comment: If the "textfile" contains a character of value `0` it's kinda exaggeration to call it a text file.

Comment: Are you sure that the format string is being read in properly?  If `format` contains the string `"\r"` (the three-character sequence you've stated is in the file), then `sprintf` should put the single character `'\r'` (and terminating `'\0'`) into `target`...

Comment: format does not contain  the string "\r" it contains the string "\\r".

Comment: i lied about the textfile - one line contains "\\r\n", the "\n" is irrelevant for the problem and i can easily filter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standard functions that will do the un-escaping for you, so you will have to do it yourself.

```
void unescape(const char *in, char *out)
{
    int esc = 0;

    while (*in) {

       if (esc) {

          switch(*in) {
           case 'r':
              *out++ = '\r';
              break;
           case 'n':
              *out++ = '\n';
              break;
           default:
              *out++ = '\\';
              *out++ = *in;
              break;
          }

          esc = 0;

        } else if (*in == '\\') {
          esc = 1;
       } else {
          *out++ = *in;
       }

       in++;
   }

 *out = 0;
}
```

(*note, the 'out' buffer must be at least as large as the 'in' buffer. And if the last char is a \, it is lost)

You'd then do

```
char input[BUFSZ];
char buf[BUFSZ];

//read data from the file into 'input'

unescape(input, buf);
sprintf(target, buf, ...);
```

Comment: ok, i think there is nothing else i can do... i will speak to the customer about what he really needs and see if i can get around doiing the above.

Answer (score 2):

The double `""` make a string out of `\r`, whereas `'\r'` refers to a single character or an escaped sequence. You might use `strcat`-function and append a single character to your format, as strcat requires `const char*`.
Try

```
strcat(format, '\r');
```

of course, you will need to provide sufficient memory.

As Oli Charlesworth provided, take your string and

```
len = strlen(str); str[len] = '\r';
str[len+1] = '\0';
```

In that particular case, you are writing over your string.

Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/).

Comment: the format string is externally provided and contains the three characters '\\', 'r', '\0'. I am not free to hardcode '\r'.

Comment: `strcat` takes a `const char *` as its 2nd argument, not a `char`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So cast it then?

Comment: You can't meaningfully cast a `char` to a `const char *`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So, what do you suggest?

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure what your answer is suggesting, so I don't know!

Comment: Well, one option is `strcat(str, "\r")`.  Another is `len = strlen(str); str[len] = '\r'; str[len+1] = '\0';`.

Comment: I do have functionality like that in my code.
But i cant do that because the user may decide tomorrow that the file contains '\\' 'n' '\0' or something completely different. I have to use some function to parse and interprete the multichar escape like it were written during compile time.

Comment: @Johannes: Wait, the *format* string is externally loaded?  That sounds like a security problem waiting to happen. (Using `sprintf` instead of `snprintf` also is likely to be asking for trouble.)

Answer (score 2):

Can you `sprintf` it **twice**?

If your original file has `"\\r"` (three non-null chars), the first run through `sprintf` would create a target of `"\r"` (two non-null chars, with the backslash escaped).

Then you could use that as the **format** string for the next `sprintf`, which should create a target of `'\r'` (the single carriage return character).

**Edit:** This will not work well if the original format string does not escape the format specifiers as well (the `%`).

Comment: I will experiment with this. The customer agreed to drop the usecase, he does not really need it. Sometimes the solution is not programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Parse the external format and build the (internal) format as required, eg:

```
if ((externalformat[0] == '\\')
      && ((externalformat[1] == 'r')
      && ((externalformat[2] == 0))
{
    strcpy(format, "\r");
}

/* use format */
sprintf(target, format, ...);
```

Comment: That would be my last straw, i hope there are other options. But you did understand my problem there.